# Windows 2008 r2 debugview (OutputDebugString) issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

Hi we are installing x86 application as a service on windows 2008 R2 which is using [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) for debug messages.

The problem is that [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) utility catches the debug output from the application only when application is run from console in elevated mode and not as a service.

I haven't found any KB that talks directly about this limitation of OutputDebugString in windows 2008 R2.

Anyone encountered such a problem? Is there such limitation really exists?

UPD: We are using terminal services to connect to server if that important

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** [This seems to be a fix for the issue](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/dbmutex.html) Its a special kernel mode driver that creates the mutex correctly.

Windows Debuggers and [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) uses a mutex, a shared memory buffer and two events to pass the messages back and forth. It seems that sometimes a [permission error](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html) can occur when trying to read the messages. Perhaps this is happening when writing the messages.

I would think that profiling the application with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) would be the best way to find the CreateMutex call short of stepping through the disassembly with [WinDbg](http://www.windbg.org/).